# Persisting association in batches with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Message` entity and a `Recipient` entity, where the former has a unidirectional `ManyToMany` relationship to the latter, as such (with boilerplate code removed):

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "message_recipient", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "message_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipient_id"))
    private Set<Recipient> recipients;
}
```

Now I would like to persist a message into the database, but I want to associate the message with *many* recipients, sometimes potentially many thousands. Therefore I want to avoid keeping a set of thousands of objects in memory, but instead persist the association in batches, such that only X recipients are in memory at a time. My idea was that I could do something like the following pseudo-ish code.

```
Message message = new Message();
Set<Recipient> recipients = first 500 recipients

while (recipients != null) {
    message.setRecipients(recipients);
    messageRepository.saveAndFlush(message);

    if (there are more recipients to save) {
        recipients = next 500 recipients
    } else {
        recipients = null;
    }
}
```

My assumption/hope was that Hibernate would detect that no changes had been done to the properties of the `message` entity except for the `recipients` association, and due to the cascade type being set to `persist`, the new recipients would be added in addition to the recipients that had already been persisted. However, what actually happens is that the recipients are persisted on each iteration, but then they are deleted on the next iteration before persisting the new associations. The result is that only the associations from the last iteration of the loop are persisted into the database (because the rest was deleted after being inserted).

This approach might be "hacking" Hibernate in a way that it's not supposed to be used. How could I go about persisting the association in batches such that I only keep X objects in memory at a time?

I am using Hibernate 4.3.8 with Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA.